# How can i Deploy a single npm workspace which depends on packages and other workspaces?

Tags: typescript, npm, workspace, monorepo

I created a project using npm workspaces and Typescript Project References pretty much exactly like this example repo: https://github.com/Quramy/npm-ts-workspaces-example.

This setup keeps all node_modules in the `root-directory/node_modules` and creates symlinks in the `root-directory/node_modules` folder to the packages so that they can be directly referenced from another package.

For development this works fine, but I'm stuck at the deployment. How would I deploy a single workspace if all node modules are in the root? The dist folders do not contain the node modules and `npm i` installs all dependencies and creates all symlinks.

#### How can I create a build for a single workspace which depends on packages and another workspace without including all dependencies from all workspaces?

The Structure looks as following:

```
├── node_modules/
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── package-1
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   │   ├── helper.d.ts
│   │   │   ├── helper.js
│   │   │   ├── helper.js.map
│   │   │   ├── main.d.ts
│   │   │   ├── main.js
│   │   │   └── main.js.map
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   ├── helper.ts
│   │   │   └── main.ts
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── package-2
│       ├── dist
│       │   ├── index.d.ts
│       │   ├── index.js
│       │   └── index.js.map
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       │   └── index.ts
│       └── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.build.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Anyone found a solution yet?

Comment: If you arent fully commited yet i highly suggest using nest.js, it has full support for a monorepo/libraries structure and everything just works. It creates builds for the different services and can be controlled with a CLI just like angular

Answer (score -1):

I don't know a solution for this using npm workspaces. But if you switch from npm to pnpm, there is a command that does exactly this: [deploy](https://pnpm.io/cli/deploy)